# Want to calculate capital

Tags: python-3.x

I want to save a certain amount of money into savings account at the rate of 5% for 10 years. I need $10000.00 at the end of the 10 years.

Task is to know the capital or the initial investment

```
futureValue=(10000)
interestRate=(0.05)
depositePeriod=(10)
capital=futureValue/(1+interestRate)*depositePeriod
print(capital)
```

I get 95238.xxxxx. but i expect something like 952.00

because capital should not be more interest at the end of the period

Comment: The exponentiation operator is `**`, `*` is multiplication (also be aware that `*` has the same precedence as `/`, so you'll need parentheses if you want multiplication but want the denominator multiplied).

Answer (score 0):

this is more of a math problem then a code, but here, this FOR loop would give you the answer you're looking for

```
futureValue=(10000)
interestRate=(0.05)
depositePeriod=(10)
capital = futureValue
for no_of_years in range(depositePeriod):
    capital = capital/(1+interestRate)
print(capital)
```